# Apigee proxy with trailing slash "/"

Tags: apigee

I Have an API Proxy, with two flows, one which returns the details of an item following the pattern "/items/{itemId}" and another one following the pattern: `/items`

```
<Flows>
    <Flow name="Items by Id">
    <Condition>((proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath &quot;/{Items}&quot;) ) and (request.verb = &quot;GET&quot;)</Condition>
</Flow>

<Flow name="List of Episodes">
    <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath &quot;/&quot;) and (request.verb = &quot;GET&quot;)</Condition>
</Flow>
```

Now, I want to support trailing `/` to both end points and here is the issues I am facing. When i try and invoke the API with trialing `/` for `/Items/` call, Apigee assumes it to be `/Items/{itemId}` with `Items = ""` and hence redirects and executes a different flow.

Please advice on how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add another line to the flow to capture both:

```
<Flows>
    <Flow name="Items list">
        <Condition>((proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath '/Items') or (proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath '/Items/') and (request.verb = 'GET')</Condition>
    </Flow>
    <Flow name="Items by Id">
        <Condition>((proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath '/items/{itemId}')) and (request.verb = 'GET')</Condition>
    </Flow>
<Flows>
```

Or if you're really clever you can just add them both to the same conditional line using an 'or'.

Comment: The problem with add an or condition or the above is, when I invoke a "/" it assumes the call to be "/{ItemId}" with the ItemId = "" and hence lands in the wrong flow

Comment: @SathyaNagarjun I'm not sure what you mean? Your original example doesn't say anything about ItemId. Perhaps you've got the flow entirely wrong? See my edit and see if that works.